# Fixed header needing transparency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a div for my header which uses position: fixed in css to stay in place. However, I'd like to add some transparency on the div (div's background which uses a #color)when scrolled content goes under it.

Is that possible with CSS? My bet is on some kind of JavaScript (jQuery perhaps)? I'm not that familiar with JS, any example would be great.

Thanks, Andrei.

PS: I'm not using any images for either page background, or header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `opacity` on the div.  Values `0-1` the lower the value the more transparent the div.

jQuery

```
$('#divID').css('opacity','.4');
```

It can be done in plain css as well

```
#divId {
    opacity:.4;
}
```

**Update**

If you only want your header to be transparent while scrolling you will need to do something like this using jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#divID').css('opacity','.4');
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $('#divID').css('opacity','1');
    }, 250));
});
```

**Update 2**

If you only want your header to be transparent when the window is scrolled down.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() == 0)
        $('#divID').css('opacity','1');
    else
        $('#divID').css('opacity','.4');
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/VZU9K/

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for your reply. Would it be OK if i wrap your code in <script> tags, or should I call for some JS file first?

Comment: @PopaAndrei reading your question again.. I'm wondering if you only want it transparent when the window is not scrolled all the way to the top.. I'll post one more option.

Comment: here's a link to the two states: picture 1 is the initial state, picture 2 is where I want transparency to happen. http://postimg.org/gallery/9viz5fbi/

The purple(ish) div has to go transparent while the other content (red div and such) is scrolling.

Comment: @PopaAndrei check my `Update 2` and example.  That should work out for  you.

Comment: @PopaAndrei are you having trouble finding the `id` or `class` to your header?  Do you understand how selecting elements in jQuery works?

Comment: The example you posted on jsfiddle works perfectly. However, when I try to use it in my project nothing happens. Here's what I did, maybe you could correct me if I'm wrong: I called jQuery inside the <head> tag via <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>. After that, I've loaded the code from your update 2 using <script></script> inside the body. changed the #divID into #header, which is my header div. What am I missing?

Comment: Try this. `<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>` inside your `head` tag.. Like you said.  Then in the body try <script>$(document).ready(function(){alert('test');});</script> And see if you can see the `test` alert box pop up.

Comment: Tried that, the pop-up loads just fine. It's the first thing I've tried to see if the path is correct... Here's a screenshot of the actual code I'm using. I've highlighted the section for you.. http://postimg.org/image/fhyrsbn4r/

Comment: @PopaAndrei Ahh I see now.  Your `header` has a `class` of `header` instead of an `id`. So change `#header` to `.header`.  `.` is for selecting classes.

Comment: Works great, Thanks a lot Trevor, I really appreciate it. Andrei

Answer (score 1):

To set opacity on a background you need to use rgba instead of the hexadecimal code for the background color. You can do this with css:

```
#div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

The first three numbers are red, green, blue, and can range from 0 to 255, the final number is the opacity which has a range of .0 (0%) to 1 (100%).

For quick conversions from a hexadecimal code to rgb I usually use a site like: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm

Josh

Comment: Why would you be worried about IE8? IE8 does not support modern web standards and Google is dropping support for it in many of their products by the end of 2013. Browser share is already a paltry 7% and falling. I wouldn't waste time worrying about IE8 unless you are coding for a corporate intranet and forced to.

Comment: In this case, it's better to play it safe then sorry. What you have, if a user is on IE8, will turn that div black if rgba is not supported...

Answer (score 0):

You could set following background-color in css of that div. 0.7 is the opacity value.

> background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.7);

Answer (score 0):

You can either use opacity:

```
/* Note that opacity will apply to all descendant elements as well, */
/* so all your links/text/logo will inherit the opacity value as well.*/

.header {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

or give just make the background translucent using HSLA or RGBA.

```
.header {
    background: #F00F00; /* background color for <IE8 */
    background: hsla(100, 50%, 50%, 0.5); 
    /* the last value (0.5) determines the opacity */
}
```

Comment: @MikeBarwick yup, but this is progressive enhancement. The IE8 and lower users will still be able to use the website just fine without a translucent background :)

Comment: Won't the background fall back to the color `black`?

Comment: @MikeBarwick you're right, I neglected to provide a fallback. I've edited my answer. Thanks.